# Get value from closure and add to numberOfRowsInSection swift

Tags: swift, closures

I have a closure

```
getCitiesFromServer() { (success, result) in

                countТ = Array(success.values).count

}
```

So I want to use it for generate count of cells in table:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

return countТ
}
```

How to get `countT` from closure and add to `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: You should assign `Array(success.values)` to a data source array e.g.  `cities` and return `cities.count` in `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just reload the tableView once the completion is done like this :

```
getCitiesFromServer() { (success, result) in

            countТ = Array(success.values).count
            tableview.reloadData()

}
```

like this the count will be taken from the new datasource.

But a better practice will be to have in numberOfRowsInSection returning something like

```
datasource.count
```

where

```
datasource = Array(success.values)
```

and have declared datasource as a class variable